# compare two time values with system current time

Tags: java, android, calendar

i'm creating a simple attendance app i want to get system's current time, and if the current time is between 8 a.m to 3 pm then set value as "Morning". Below is my code i'm getting error at 'before' and 'after' methods of calendar class. Kindly suggest me the right way to use it.

```
try {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
        String currentTime = sdf.format(c.getTime());

        // start time
         String lwrLimit = " 08:30:00 AM";  
        java.util.Date time_1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(lwrLimit);
        Calendar calendar_1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_1.setTime(time_1);

        // end time
        String  uprLimit  = " 03:59:59 PM";  
        java.util.Date time_2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(uprLimit);
        Calendar calendar_2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar_2.setTime(time_2);

     if (currentTime.after(time_1) && currentTime.before(time_2)) 
          {
             ed_shift.setText( "Morning");
          }


    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: And in general, you shouldn't use `HH` and `a` together. What would you expect "15:00:00 AM" to give you when you parse it? (And why are you parsing values at all for hard-coded times?)

Comment: @kalyanpvs  no yr :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check like this

```
   Calendar presentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    startDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    endDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    endDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    endDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if (presentDate.after(startDate) && presentDate.before(endDate)) {
        // set morning here
    } else {
        // set your data here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, before and after methods are looked for in java.lang.String class as currentTime is defined to be a String in the beginning.